# passing a vector member variable by reference to another class method

Tags: c++, reference

NOTE: I use pseudocode in my question

lets say i have a class called circle with an interface called
circle.h which 
i also have a method called readdata but this is defined in another
class called rectangle(rectangle.h is the interface )
i want to call the method readdata in my circle class and pass in my
private member variable which is a vector. How can this be done? is it
correct to pass in a PRIVATE member variable by reference
to another class. Isn't this defeating the whole purpose of having
private member variables because now i am giving class rectangle
access to circle class vector variable since i pass it in by reference. Here is how i
do it(psuedocode)

```
circle.h

private:
vector<struct> vect;

public:
dataread()

circle.cpp

rectangle.h

readdata(vector &)




method dataread() //class method to fill up my struct
{
 rectangle::readdata(vect);   //i call rectangle readdata method but i
 pass in a reference to my memebr variable....is this safe?
}
```

should i just declare the vector locally(in dataread method) and
assign it to the reference? any help would be greatly appreciated.
Right now it compiles but i have been told this is not good
programming practice

Comment: You might want to formulate your question a bit clearer, because it is quite hard to understand what you are asking (furthermore: why pseudocode? Might be easier to udnerstand your question with the real code). As a side note `circle.h` is a header file not an interface. And really without knowing anything about the classes, their invariants and the the pre/postconditions of the methods there is no way for us to answer your question...

Comment: If this is a design question, you need to explain more what your design is. In some cases it might make sense to pass a private by reference. I'm not sure why something called Circle has a vector in it or what that has to do with a Rectangle though.. Also, something called readdata shouldn't modify the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you are asking.  Yes, you can pass a reference to your private data and No, you shouldn't do it.  You can pass a const reference so that it can't be modified or pass a new vector with the contents copied.  The best thing to figure out is why you need to do it that way, then figure out the best method for getting the data there.

Comment: Generally speaking there is nothing wrong with passing a reference to private data to a method/function. The question doesn't give enough information to say whether or not its correct *in this specific case*.

Comment: it seesm like it is a matter of trust. Because if i pass the a reference to a private member of a class (the vector) and the user fills it up with values(structs) and leaves the scope of rwaddata, he still maintains the reference to my private variable and can fill it up with corrupted or invalid data for further use. If i use a local copy is readdata method, then the other class has no reference to my vector and thus cannot mess with it

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with passing references to private members to methods in other classes.  For example:

```
void myClass::myMethod() {
    std::copy(myVector1.begin(), myVector1.end(), myVector2.begin());
}
```

While that doesn't pass a reference to myVector1 directly, it does pass a writable iterator which is just about the same thing.  The class is making a request for some object/function to do something with its data.  So long as that other object/function only does what it is supposed to do, there's no problem.

Comment: "So long as that other object/function only does what it is supposed to do, there's no problem". I think you shouldn't rely on this. The encapsulation (private members) is (are) meant to offer protection in a non-collaborative environment.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a pointer to a "private memory area" is not necessarily against the encapsulation idea because the object owning that memory area decides whom to allow access to. It doesn't allow "anyone to access it". On the other hand this doesn't look very natural.

You should return a pointer from the readdata method and use it in your circle instance.
At the same time doing this breaks a principle which I, personally, use: the one who allocates memory is responsible for it so it should also be the one frees it when appropriate. Taking this into consideration, it would probably be a good idea to return the actual vector and not a pointer to it (but this means copying a large amount of memory in case you're not using a compiler with "return value optimization").

Comment: "but this means copying a large amount of memory": not necessarily: return-value optimization exactly avoids this kind of inefficiency.

Comment: I was talking about the theoretical concepts. You're talking about some compilers optimizations which are certainly not available in all existing compilers.

Comment: RVO is a theoretical concept: in fact, it is part of the language. Moreover, every non-horribly-ancient compiler supports it.

Comment: If it's part of the language it should be supported by every conforming compiler. So it's not a matter of "horribly-ancient" or not. 
However, Wikipedia says this: return value optimization is supported on most compilers.

Comment: Maybe you missed that thing from Wikipedia: "The term return value optimization refers to **a special clause in the C++ standard** that allows an implementation to omit a copy operation resulting from a return statement, even if the copy constructor has side effects, something that is not permitted by the as-if rule alone.".
It is not enforced, but implementation are allowed to do so (and they do, try yourself).